# How to find categorical contributing factors for an anomaly?

Tags: clustering, outliers, anomaly-detection, change-point

Given a house sales dataset with number of houses sold each day and their attributes (i.e., price, number of rooms, size, etc.) - if on a specific day there's a spike/drop in sales, what are some techniques to automatically identify in which segments/combination of sub-segments were these drops? for example: the drop was because there were a lot less top priced, large houses sold.

Also, is there a technical name for this problem? I'd like to search and read more about it

Answer (score 0):

Hello you may start with reading [Contextual Outlier Interpretation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10589.pdf). You may also adapt [LIME](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime) for the scenario of outlier detection. The key idea is to assume that you can model the local decision boundary by a linear model. Then you are able to interpret influence of variables on the outlier score.